# Too many files open error. Not sure if Linux restriction or PDF Lib restriction

Tags: php, linux, pdflib

I am generating a large 1000 page check template and get the following error when I run from X-post

"Error: Couldn't open PDF file '(output file name and location)' for reading (too many open files)"

When I go into adjust my quantity down from 1000 t0 959 it works. I have tried upping my fs.max-file to 6000000 but it does not work.

```
    //works
$qty = '959';   

// Looping thru the start Numbers
for ($i = $qty; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if($i == $qty){
        $newNo1 = $this->orderData->check_number;
    }


    //Does NOT work
$qty = '1000';   

// Looping thru the start Numbers
for ($i = $qty; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if($i == $qty){
        $newNo1 = $this->orderData->check_number;
    }
```

So does anyone know whether this is a Linux issue or possibly restrictions on PDF Lib?

Comment: I've used Pdflib's C interface to create 200,000+ page PDF files, so I doubt that it is a limitation of PDFLib. (I was using PDFLib 7 from PDFLib GmbH, I believe the open source version is stuck back at PDFLib 3.something)

Comment: What type of server were you on?

Comment: Code I have that does this is ported and tested on Linux, HP-UX, Solaris, AIX, Windows, and even OS/400.

Comment: It's definitely our server. Seems to limiting the amount of open files to only users. We tried upping our global amount but it still did not work.

Comment: You made it sound like the limitation was on pages (1000 page template)... but are you actually generating multiple PDFs (=open files) in parallel or something?  The OSs will limit you on max number of open files on a per-user and per-process basis.

Comment: Yes, sorry let me explain better. We have numbers on our checks. So each page will have a new number. So we have to create/open a new page per check. The quantity is 1000. Only lets us create/open 959 per user. I have looked everywhere but no answer.

Comment: Are you remembering to close your pages after writing them with PDF_end_page_ext?

Comment: There are internal counters which will overflow if you do not close your documents